How to update the version in azure devops pipeline
I am having the below task in my azure pipeline
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Publish to Azure Artifact feed'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/abc'
    feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
    vstsFeedPublish: 'xyz'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: 'bundle'
    versionOption: 'custom'
    **versionPublish: '1.0.0'**
    publishedPackageVar: 'ReleaseBundle#1'

my question is
when the pipeline is automatically triggered, how can I update the value of versionPublish
so that the artifact is stored in the feed with a new version

What exactly do you mean by new version? Increment the patch? minor? major?

According to the UniversalPackages@0 task documentation, versionOption is used to specify a version increment strategy.
Allowed values are the following:

major (Next major): the first version will be 1.0.0
minor (Next minor): the first version will be 0.1.0
patch (Next patch): the first version will be 0.0.1
custom: value to input your package version manually

Values will be incremented automatically when using versionOption: major, versionOption: minor or versionOption: patch.
You should only use versionOption: custom if you want to have full control over the way the version is generated, for example using the counter expression to construct an incremental version number.

That worked. Appreciate for the help. I also want to know when the patch is incremented to 0.0.9 what will be the next increment number

@kiranitagi it will be 0.0.10

Suppose i want the increment to be 0.1.0 after 0.0.9 how can i achieve that

@kiranitagi you change the versionOption from patch to minor

@kiranitagi please read https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/what-is-semantic-versioning/
